# How to add listener to a GroupLayer in playn?

Tags: java, gwt, listener, playn

I have used Pointer.Listener and Mouse.Listener  with ImageLayer and it worked. But when I use Pointer.Listener to a GroupLayer, It doesnt listens the clicks or touches. How can I do this?

I am using the following code.

```
myGroupLayer.addListener(new Pointer.Listener() {
  @Override
  public void onPointerEnd(Event event) {
    System.out.println("click registered");
    myMethodToRun();
  }
  @Override
  public void onPointerDrag(Event event) { }
  @Override
  public void onPointerStart(Event event) { }
});
```

Comment: If you're unable to attach a listener to a GroupLayer, an alternative approach would be to set a listener on the pointer and then trigger the event on condition of a collision between pointer event location and the GroupLayer. An example of concept can be found here: [PlaynDev.java](http://code.google.com/p/klenwell/source/browse/trunk/projects/java/playndev/playndev/core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/klenwell/playndev/core/PlaynDev.java#55)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A GroupLayer will never itself be "hit" by a mouse click. One of the children of the GroupLayer could be hit, but that won't trigger a listener registered on the group layer, only on the child itself.

If you have a GroupLayer that contains multiple children, and you want the event to be dispatched to the GroupLayer's listener when any of those children are clicked, then you have to use a custom hit tester on the GroupLayer:

```
myGroupLayer.setHitTester(new Layer.HitTester() {
  public Layer hitTest(Layer l, Point p) {
    Layer hitLayer = myGroupLayer.hitTestDefault(p);
    return (hitLayer != null) ? myGroupLayer : null;
  }
});
```

This will cause your GroupLayer to hit test all of its children, and if any of the children are hit, it returns *itself* as the hit layer. Then listeners registered on your group layer will be run as if the group layer itself were clicked.

Comment: `setHitTester` didn't work for me, I added a log and it kept loggin `hitlayer = null` wherever I point my mouse cursor (I also debugged the `Point p` and it shows correct coordinates).

Comment: OK i just did some debugging and saw that children layers should be set to interactive..